# Does it change anything when I disable obsolete parameters in SQL Backups? SKIP , stats, Nounload , norewind etc

Tags: sql-server, backup, database-backup, sql-server-2012

I am pretty new in managing Computersystems but I always want to know everything to get out the maximum.

When we last time deployed a new version of our application I was given a backup script to backup a specific Database.

I saw backup parameters like :

- skip
- nounload
- norewind
- stats

I found out that nounload (no-unload) will not unload a tape if you backup on tape
norewind will not rewind the tape
and stats will diplays the process in %  (stats 1; = 1% steps or stats 10 are 10% steps)

I wonder what `SKIP`  is doing, since google didn't want to help me, and I also would love to know if it changes ANYTHING when I skip all this.

It just looks cleaner for me when i remove all unnecessery stuff from my scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx). SKIP and NOSKIP arguments controls whether a backup operation checks the expiration date and time of the backup sets on the media before overwriting them.

SKIP disables the checking of backup set expiration and name that is usually performed by the BACKUP statement to prevent overwrites of backup sets.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use **[SQL Server Backup solution](http://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html)** from ola hallengren.

TO answer your question : Below is reference from [BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx)

[image]

Comment: thanks for the info. So you think it will not change anything if i keep or skip the parameters?